# Javascript function disappears

Tags: javascript, function, lambda, lisp

I am trying to implement a small subset of the programming language LISP, using JavaScript as source language. When the this small lisp is fed the a string looking like this:

```
(define func (lambda (args)(body)))
```

This is then being passed to a function called CreateLambda.
For example, the following string is being passed:

```
(define add (lambda(x y)(+ x y)))
```

A Javascript function is then created by this function;

```
function createLambda(expr, env) { // lambda args body
    expr.shift(); //remove the "lambda".
    var lambdaArgs = expr.shift(); //get the arguments
    var lambdaBody = expr.shift(); // get the body
    var parentEnvironment = env;
    return function() {
        var lambdaEnvironment = new environment(parentEnvironment, "lambda environment");
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var tempVal = evaluate(arguments[i], parentEnvironment);
            lambdaEnvironment.add(lambdaArgs[i], tempVal);
        }
        return evaluate(lambdaBody, lambdaEnvironment);
    }
}
```

Later, if this function is being called and evaluated in the small lisp, something like this:

```
(add 2 3)
```

This string is being picked up by the evaluate loop in a case that looks like this:

```
else if(typeof expr[0] === 'string') {
    var lispFunc = env.get(expr[0]); //find the function in the environment.
    expr.shift(); 
    var lispFuncArgs = [];
    var tempArg = expr.shift();
    while(tempArg != null) { //apply the variables
        lispFuncArgs.push(evaluate(tempArg, env));
        tempArg = expr.shift();
    }
    return lispFunc.apply(this, lispFuncArgs);
```

The first time it is being passed to the evaluate-function, it works as intended and it returns the number 5.

However, if the same function is called again. it enters the evaluate loop only as "undefined".

Full HTML;

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="Content-Script-
Type" content="text/javascript">
        <title>LISP in JavaScript</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="lisp.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="repl" name="repl" action="parse(prompt.value)">
               lisp==&gt;
            <input id="prompt" size="200" value="" name="prompt" 
maxlength="512">
            <br>
            <input type=button style="width:60px;height:30px" name="btnEval" 
value="eval" onclick="output(prompt.value)">
            <br>
            </form>
        <div id="debugdiv" style="background-
color:orange;width=100px;height=20px">
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Full JavaScript;

```
//functions for parsing input String

function parse(exp) {
    return readFromTokes(tokenize(exp)); //code
}

function isNumeric(arg) {
    return !isNaN(arg);
}

function readFromTokes(exp) {
   //Create abstract syntax tree
   if(exp.length == 0) {
   }
   var token = exp.shift();
   if(token == '(') {
       var L = [];
       while(exp[0] != ')') {
           L.push(readFromTokes(exp));
       }         
       exp.shift(); //remove end paranthesis
       return L;
   } else {
       if(token == ')') {
           console.log("Unexpected )");
       } else {
           return atom(token);
       }
   }
}

function tokenize(exp) {
    //Convert a program in form of a string into an array (list)
    var re = /\(/g;
    var re2 = /\)/g;
    exp = exp.replace(re, " ( ");
    exp = exp.replace(re2, " ) ");
    exp = exp.replace(/\s+/g, ' ');
    exp = exp.trim().split(" ");
    return exp;
}

function atom(exp){
    if(isNumeric(exp)) {
        return parseInt(exp); //A number is a number
    } else {
        return exp; //Everything else is a symbol
    }
}

function environment(parentEnvironment, name) {
    var bindings = [];
    var parent = parentEnvironment;
    var name = name;

    function add(variable, value) {
        console.log("variable: " + variable + " value: " + value);
        bindings.push([variable, value]);
    }

    function printName() {
        console.log(name);
    }

    function print() {
        console.log("printing environment: ")
        for(var i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
            console.log(bindings[i][0] + " " + bindings[i][1]);
        }
    }

    function get(variable) {
        for(var i = 0; i < bindings.length; i++) {
            if(variable == bindings[i][0]) {
                return bindings[i][1];
            }
        }
        if(parent != null) {
            return parent.get(variable);
        } else {
            console.log("No such variable");
        }
    }

    function getParent(){
        return parent;
    }

    this.add = add;
    this.get = get;
    this.getParent = getParent;
    this.print = print;
    this.printName = printName;
    return this;
}

function addPrimitives(env) {
    env.add("+", function() {
        var s = 0; 
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
            s += arguments[i]; 
        } 
        return s
    });
    env.add("-", function() {
        var s = arguments[0]; 
        for(var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) { 
            s -= arguments[i];
        } 
        return s
    });
    env.add("*", function() {
        var s = 1; 
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){ 
            s *= arguments[i];
        } 
        return s
    });
    env.add("/", function(x, y) { return x / y });
}


function createLambda(expr, env) { // lambda args body
    expr.shift(); //remove the "lambda".
    var lambdaArgs = expr.shift(); //get the arguments
    var lambdaBody = expr.shift(); // get the body
    var parentEnvironment = env;
    return function() {
        var lambdaEnvironment = new environment(parentEnvironment, "lambda 
       environment");
        for(var i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
            var tempVal = evaluate(arguments[i], parentEnvironment);
            lambdaEnvironment.add(lambdaArgs[i], tempVal);
        }
        return evaluate(lambdaBody, lambdaEnvironment);
    }
}

function evaluate(expr, env) {
    console.log(expr + " has entered evaluate loop");
    env.printName();
    env.print();
    if(typeof expr === 'string') {
        console.log(expr + " is a symbol");
        return env.get(expr);
    } else if(typeof expr === 'number') {
        console.log(expr + " is a number");
        return expr;
    } else if(expr[0] === 'define') { // (define var value)
        console.log(expr + " is a define statement");
        expr.shift(); 
        var newVar = expr.shift();
        var newVal = evaluate(expr.shift(), env);
        env.add(newVar, newVal);
        return env;
    } else if (expr[0] === 'lambda') { // (lambda args body)
        console.log(expr + " is a lambda statement");
        return createLambda(expr, env);
    } else if (typeof expr[0] === 'string'){
        var lispFunc = env.get(expr[0]);
        expr.shift();
        var lispFuncArgs = [];
        var tempArg = expr.shift();
        while(tempArg != null) {
            lispFuncArgs.push(evaluate(tempArg, env));
            tempArg = expr.shift();
        }
        console.log("Function: " + lispFunc);
        console.log("Arguments: " + lispFuncArgs);
        return lispFunc.apply(this, lispFuncArgs);
    } else {
        console.log(expr + " cannot be interpreted");
    }
}


var globalEnvironment = new environment(null, "Global");

addPrimitives(globalEnvironment);

function start(string) {
    return evaluate(parse(string), globalEnvironment);
}

var output = function (string) {
    try {
        document.getElementById('debugdiv').innerHTML = start(string);
    } catch(e) {
        document.getElementById('debugdiv').innerHTML = e.name + ': ' + e.message;
    }
};
```

Comment: the `lambdaBody` variable inside the closure becomes `[]`, but I don't know why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because there is a tiny bug in your code.
When you call the `evaluate(lambdaBody, lambdaEnvironment)` at line:134, you provide `lambdaBody` as the first argument, which is the `expr` argument in the 'function evaluate(expr, env)' function (line:138). During your evaluation you consume it with  `tempArg = expr.shift();` function and get out of the loop when its empty. For the second time, your `lambdaBody` is unfortunately an empty array.

To fix it, you should change the evaluate function not to modify its arguments (e.g. create a copy and consume the copy)

---

I suggest you fix the bug in the evaluate function, but a sample that really works is to change line 134 to *deep copy* `lambdaBody` as below:

```
  evaluate(lambdaBody.slice(0), lambdaEnvironment);
```

You will see that it works now no matter how many times you call it. But the bug is actually inside the evaluate function so fix it there.

Comment: Wow! It works just fine iterating over expr with a for-loop instead of consuming it with shift()! Thank you very much! I will rewrite the whole evaluate-function so that it does not use any shift.